# Generate random coordinates (excluding some specific ones)

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have a multidimensional array, which I'm using as a very simple coordinate system. To generate random coordinates, I came up with this very simple function:

```
var coords = [
  [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
  [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
  [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1],
  [1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],
  [1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],
  [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],
  [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]
];

function getRandomInt( min, max ) {
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}

function randomCoords() {
  var x, y;

  do {
    x = getRandomInt( 0, coords[ 0 ].length - 1 );
    y = getRandomInt( 0, coords.length - 1 );
  } 
  while ( coords[ y ][ x ] !== 1 );

  return [ x, y ];
}
```

As you might see, I only want to get random coordinates that are `1` in my array. Although this is working, I was wondering if there's a better / more effective way to do it? Sometimes (especially if there are lots of `0`s in my coordinate system) it takes a bit to return a value. In that time (as far as I know) javascript can't do anything else... so everything will just pause...

Comment: You might want to post this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: just create an array of possible coordinate pairs. Then use your random number to pick one of these pairs. Then remove the pair from the list.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Thanks, I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get a random coordinate only once or twice, then your solution is the best.

If you use it often, you can put the coordinates of the 1's in an array. So you will only have to use random() once on the array
`coordPairs1[Math.floor(Math.random() * coordPairs1.length)]`

```js
var coords = [
  [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
  [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
  [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1],
  [1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],
  [1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],
  [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],
  [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]
];

// make coord-pairs:
var coordPairs1 = []
for(var x=0; x<coords[0].length; ++x) {
    for(var y=0; y<coords.length; ++y) {
        if(coords[y][x] == 1)
            coordPairs1.push([x,y])
    }
}

function randomCoords() {
    return coordPairs1[Math.floor(Math.random() * coordPairs1.length)]
}

// Example:
document.body.innerHTML = randomCoords()
```

Comment: Thanks, that'll work. I think you forgot to check for the array value (1) in your for-loop though...

Comment: What are you making? A Game?

Comment: Yes, a canvas game. The array is the map (top view) and all `0` are walls etc. and not walkable. I just needed to find a simple way to get random coordinates where you can walk to.